# What is the word for when people use associative words for technical terms?

Tags: synonyms, terminology, technical, metaphors

Examples:

- the word "canned" is used for multiple items within a list
- "breadcrumbs" is used for specifying a part of a webpage used for navigation on the site
- "bootstrap" is used for start up (an Internet-based business or other enterprise) with minimal financial resources, among many other meanings.

Is there a word that signifies these "metaphors"?

Comment: What in your opinion separates these metaphors from others? The fact that the ones you mention are more recent than many (and punchier, probably for precisely that reason) just shows that new metaphors arise constantly. Arguably, they make the transition to 'dead metaphors' more quickly too: I'm sure you'd find these three new senses given in many dictionaries. Clusters of metaphors often arise in certain areas (eg nautical expressions, farming expressions, army expressions ...) and technical language is just continuing the practice of using existing terms in novel ways.

Comment: What separates them is that they're used as standard words over time, giving a new meaning to the same word used before.

Comment: No; that's true for all metaphors to differing degrees. Including single word examples. 'Mouse' (the device) may be a relatively new usage, but 'cat' (the fellow) predates it and 'cat' (the whip) vastly predates it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Actually, the above terms are quite old (with the possible exception of "canned").  They've simply been repurposed.  There's absolutely nothing remarkable about them or their use as "technical" terms.

Comment: More details on metaphor [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf), and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf), and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/91228/15299), and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf), for instance.

Comment: I'd say that if anything separated such metaphors that are recent jargon from those like *computer*, *brand new*, *fall in love*, *run out of time*, *coinage*, *diverge* and so on, is that they have in fact not yet fully become "standard" words and we still understand them as metaphors on first reading rather than as "standard" words and phrases that happen to originate in metaphors.

Comment: @ Hot Licks I said the metaphor[ical usage], not the terms themselves, were quite recent. I illustrated this with " 'Mouse' (the device) may be a relatively new usage" etc. But thank you for repeating the point.

Comment: What Jon said actually.

Comment: Then in that case the description that differentiates them is merely *recent*.

Answer (score 1):

The "shortcut" words - rather than the technical terms - of different trades/industries/disciplines, are known as *jargon*.

Comment: Yes I also found them to be "tech-slang". A more suitable word awated.