# Is it bad English to substitute the word 'says' with 'goes'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english

In the Midwest, I notice that some people substitute the word 'says' with 'goes' and this has always bothered me. For example, I will hear someone say something such as "So my mother goes, "you should drink water instead of soda."" instead of "So my mother says, "you should drink water instead of soda."".

Is this simply bad English?

Comment: It's not "formal" English, but perfectly acceptable in most informal contexts.  Note that it does carry a "tone" (one that I can't offhand characterize) that isn't present with "says".

Comment: Similarly almost every English speaking youth on planet earth is like "And I was like "xyz", and he was like "bla-bla-bla", and then I was like "blo-blo-blo". - The question is, what register of language are you speaking about? In a written piece of text such a newspaper article, an official report, a polite letter to your grandparents you would not use those very casual, oral expressions. If you are writing drama and you want to show youngster in their ordinary attitude, you would write it.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann - "Like" is a bit more down in the Valley.

Comment: @ ChristianGeiselmann, I hear this mostly in casual dialog between friends or family.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I question your implication that politeness be associated with letters to grandparents. You have an ageless, idealised image of the species. What age are we living in?  I am a grandparent, and my grandchildren do not write me letters but send texts and emails. And the idea that they would be more "polite" with me than with anyone else, to the extent of not saying "My mum, she goes..." is laughable.

Comment: It is not something I'd put into a college essay or a job questionnaire, but it is certainly English, and it does say something comprehensible in a way suited to expressing an attitude and a milieu. I certainly would not characterize it as *bad*, just informal.

Comment: @WS2   I am sorry that your grandchildren do not write polite letters to you. I did not mean to claim that all letters written by grandchildren to grandparents are or have to be *a priori* polite. I just wanted to give examples for situations where "and he was like x, and she was like y" would probably not be used, and therefore I specificed also a "polite letter" (as opposed to "a casual letter"). Anyway, would you find it polite to use "And I was like x, and she was like y."? Or do you have objections against the concept of politeness in general?

Comment: “Pop! says the weasel” doesn’t quite have the same ring to it…

Comment: Note that 'goes' is followed by an imitation/impression of the speaker -- there is more going on than just 'saying'.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I think you completely misinterpreted the comment about politeness and letters. It was not saying that rude letters were received. Nor was it about grandchildren being *impolite*. Rather it was saying that (a) they used text and email rather than letters, and (b) why should somebody be treated differently just because of their age? That aside, I also take issue with the statement that informal syntax should be considered impolite . . .

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet There was a young fellow called Green, Whose musical sense was not keen, He said it's most odd, But I cannot tell God save the weasel, From Pop! goes the Queen!

Comment: I think it is okay English, in that context. Not bad but not great. As the saying goes, let he who is without sin, cast the first stone.

Comment: If you're referring to a specific conversation, I think "my mother *said*" is correct rather than "says", but both "says" and "goes" are frequently used colloquially. If you're quoting something your mother is known to say generally *then* "says" would be correct and "goes" would sound odd.

Comment: Related: [How and when was it that the verb go began to mean say in common usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91223/how-and-when-was-it-that-the-verb-go-began-to-mean-say-in-common-usage?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

The OED calls that usage of [go](https://oed.com/view/Entry/79544?rskey=l67wVt&result=4#eid) *colloquial*.  It's a logical extension of the more correct usage of "go" defined as "produced sound" (i.e. "the firecracker went 'bang'").  This usage goes all the way back to the 16th century.

It's interesting to note that the earlier examples it gives refer to people making vocalizations that are not entirely words, i.e. "‘Yo-yo-yo-yo-yoe,’ went the first boy."  So it seems like using "goes" instead of "says" is something that is increasing in common usage, at least in informal situations.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the level of perfection that you want to measure up those statements. Both statements meet the fundamentals of communication to convey the message; however, if you are more concerned about correctness in the use of language, "goes" is not the proper verb to use but merely slang that is replacing "says."  Having said that, if you are concerned about some members of your readership not knowing the slang term "goes," which may cause confusion, I would stick to using "says" consistently.

Answer (score -1):

It depends how you define 'bad'.  Languages evolve, and as Janus Bahs Jacquet mentioned in comments "Pop! Says the weasel" doesn't have the right ring to it.

Where you are talking about someone/something expressing a noise (speech, sound, etc), then 'goes' has a similar understood meaning to says (perhaps not a fomal OED definition.

It also depends on the sentence. 'James goes to the shops' is obviously correct vs 'James says to the shops'. So you cannot apply a general rule that 'goes' is a bad/incorrect word to use it.

If bad referes to formality, then using 'goes' is certinaly not correct in the formal sense of the English language.

However, in the example you gave, regardless of which you use, the meaning and intent of the statement is the same.  As such it could be considered interchangeable dependant on the formality you are trying to convey or your familiarity with the other party(s) in the conversation.

Comment: Doesn't this use of *goes*, in addition to being informal, imply certain dismissiveness of what has been said? For example, doesn't the choice of *goes* instead of *says*, in the OP's example, convey the young speaker's view that the mother's advice is somewhat annoying, and that it is not worthy of being taken seriously?

Comment: This is simply an idiom of speech, possibly qualifying as juvenile slang.

Answer (score -1):

To me it's bad English to use the word "goes" instead of "said".  Example .. He goes, "My day was long".  Instead of .. He said, "My day was long". I ask .. He goes??  Where did he go?  That always stops the conversation and people look at me like huhhh? Please stop substituting goes for said.