# Why did Ylvis use "go" instead of "say" in phrases like "Dog goes 'woof'"?

Tags: lyrics

Why did [Ylvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ylvis) use the verb "go" instead of "say" in their 2013 pop song [*"What Does the Fox Say?"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_(What_Does_the_Fox_Say%3F))

> Dog goes "woof."
>   Cat goes "meow."
>   Bird goes "tweet."

Is there some specific meaning for "go"?

Comment: @1006a Apparently it doesn't sound awkward to folks in Kentucky: https://books.google.com/books?id=YSEIPwp0RUsC&pg=PA61

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm open to the possibility of dialect differences here, but I'm not sure I'd take the lyrics of an old folk song as evidence for what modern Kentuckians would find acceptable in speech.

Comment: I take it to say is to use language, otherwise to go is to make a sound.

Comment: Ylvis is Norwegian but that has nothing to do with it, it’s not lack of English skill that makes the song like this. It IS supposed to approximate how you teach a child an animal’s sound. It’s supposed to be funny.

Comment: Perhaps a slighty related expression is the use of the word "comeback" instead of the word "reply"? At first sight, "comeback" seems to be more related to "go" than to the words "reply" / "say".

Comment: It's worth noting that in Norwegian "go" means "walk", and this often causes confusion for English speakers and amusement on the part of the Norwegians listening.  As comedy is their thing, they may be sneaking in a play on words here.  Finally, it needs to be understood that this is music lyrics, and so all rules are out the window.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking Ylvis was Yiddish Elvis or something...

Comment: I like the comment by @1006a, but there's also poetic license.  I don't think them being Norwegian has much to do with it. `We Don’t Need No Education` by Pink Floyd (native English speakers), or `I Can’t Get No Satisfaction` by the Rolling Stones (native English speakers)...

Comment: Animals don't *say* things, as they don't speak. They make noises. One of the accepted colloquial parsings for the verb "to go" is to make a noise or sound.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Don't take this the wrong way, but you could edit and mention in your post that there is a [politically correct](https://genius.com/15384286) version of the line *“And the colored **girls go**...”* which is “*And the **girls** all **say**…*” That actually would support your answer even better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think I am the one that's taking it the wrong way. I saddens me that no one sees where this leads. Those who will not learn from history...

Comment: @michael.hor257k make yourself heard over at meta, you're an eloquent person.

Comment: A duplicate of [How and when was it that the verb 'go' began to mean 'say' in common usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91223/how-and-when-was-it-that-the-verb-go-began-to-mean-say-in-common-usage).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Say" applies to speech, and dogs, cats and birds can't speak.  Which means "say" is the wrong word.

What would you place there instead? "Vocalizes"?  Works for dogs, cats and birds, but what about a crickets and bees? They don't vocalize.  How about "Emits" as the catch-all for animal noises?  Way too collegiate.

There are often more specific verbs:  *The dog barks "Woof".* OK so far. *The bird tweets "Tweet"*. **That's awkward**.  *The cat coos "meow"*. Well, now we're adding meaning, since cooing suggests a different mental state than mewling or chirping (just read any mystery which involves cats trying to help).

This is a linguistic Gordian knot.

A relatively common, generic word like "Go" is about as good as this situation will get... and it's not so bad.  It adds a bit of stylistic color to the language, and certainly specifies a level of formality (or to be more precise, informality).  I wonder how a proper British butler would speak of it.

Comment: You mean "I wonder how a proper British butler would _go_ of it."? J/K

Comment: Dogs, cats, and birds communicate through vocalizations.  On the flip side, humans can vocalize without deliberate communication, such as in response to a pain reflex.    Compare "Bob said 'yoooww;' when he touched the live wire", versus "Bob let out a loud 'yoooww' when he touched the live wire.  Somehow the former suggests an excessively calm and relaxed state of mind for someone who was getting zapped.

Comment: @supercat a superlative conceptual improvement. Modified.

Comment: also everything "goes" is much easier to fit in a song

Comment: But in the exact same song, Ylvis asks *What does the fox say?* So *say* is not "the wrong word." There is absolutely nothing wrong with using *say* for animals. There's nothing wrong with using *go*, either.

Comment: '"Say" applies to speech, and dogs, cats and birds can't speak. Which means "say" is the wrong word.'

That's not how language works. Also, the song's name is literally "What does the fox say?" Language is not literal or exact 100% of the time; figurative uses of words exist.

Comment: Why not more generic "do"? I have "go" connected with movement or changing state not making sounds. --- Is this meaning of "go" similar to something like "make happen"?

Answer (score 19):

Verbs with very broad meanings like *do* or *go* get the sense of "say" in many languages. English uses "go" to mean "say" in very informal speech. There are children's songs about animal sounds that use it in this way.

Comment: Yes, for example the "speak and say" toy uses "The [animal] goes:" almost as often as "The [animal] says:" (along with variations like "Do you hear the [animal]?" and "Here is a/an [animal]:"). And of course a stereotypical teenage conversation includes sentences like *So then he goes "wait, what did the fox say?"*

Answer (score 7):

> Dog goes "woof."
> Cat goes "meow."
> Bird goes "tweet."
>
> Is there some specific meaning for "go"?

No, it's just a broad term marking an action. Much like `A dog makes woof`.

And `A bomb goes boom` is most definitely not a task of speaking - in fact, the use of go(es) is so unspecific, that here it could mean the sound as well as the explosion or the destruction.

*Say*, in contrast, includes the very specific meaning of speaking (or text to be read). It's usually not including animal sounds - unless in some transferred, poetic context (*let the wind speak* for example.)

The duality is found in next to all languages with Germanic roots - already found in 12th-century texts.

It could have as well been used in the upfront question (`What does the fox say`) as `How does the Fox go` except that usage of 'say' does explicity ask for a sound/word 'spoken' - not to mention that it's everyday kids' language :)

Comment: "A dog makes 'woof'" does not sound right to me. (The thing a dog _makes_ gets picked up in little plastic bags by conscientious dog owners...)

Comment: For that matter, "How does the fox go?" also sounds odd — not native. In fact, I'd say you can't even ask "What does the fox go?", even though "The fox goes _yelp_" is a perfectly fine answer to "What does the fox say?" — context is very important in whether "go" is an acceptable stand-in for "say".

Comment: Not only in Germanic languages: in French there is "ça va", though it's application is not as wide as "go" in English.

Comment: @mattdm Well, English covers quite some variations. Not just worldwide, but even more so when listening to native English (i.e. Speakers from England). Could it be that your 'feeling' for English is shaped by a somewhat more narrowed down variation?

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, but I'm quite certain about these. At least for American, British, and Australian speakers, with which I am most familiar

Comment: @mattdm I guess that qualifies well for the 'narrowed down' part - except mentioning the British. Then again, I've met quite some variations when travelling England. Always a recomended vacation, isn't it?

Comment: Sure. I can ask some of my Indian colleagues for what they think. Or we can ask another question about it here for a wider perspective. I'll be quite surprised if this particular thing is different in any common English variant, though.

Comment: @mattdm you realy want to open the cann labeled 'Real English'? What a bold move - I'd rather let it **go** :))

Comment: @Raffzahn What? No, I certainly do not. But, at the same time, you can't just make things up — it actually really does matter what sounds right to native speakers.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern '[Animal] goes [sound]' was widely-popularized by the [See 'n Say educational toy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_%27n_Say) produced by Mattel since 1965.

I haven't seen any official confirmation that the artist was specifically inspired by this particular pop culture gem, however.

Comment: It's funny, I had one of these and I was sure it was 'the foo says bar' so I watched some videos and it's both.  For some animals is 'says' and other's it's 'goes'.  Some don't follow the form at all.

Answer (score 3):

The MacMillan Dictionary gives many definitions of "go"; one of them is "to make a particular sound, especially the typical sound of a particular animal." "Go" would also apply to the sound of an inanimate object: for example, "toot goes the whistle" or "clang goes the bell." In those cases "says" might be understood, but "goes" is more natural.

Answer (score 3):

One of Oxford English Dictionary's definitions for go is:

> Make a sound of a specified kind. Example: "The engine went bang."

As far as I know, this is not a colloquialism, it is **the** verb to use in the case when a sound, but not speech is the direct object.

It can also be used to in reported speech, usually informally. Bit hard to find examples of this use, as you still get all the more common uses of "go", but here's an example from a Snow Patrol interview:

> The producer **said**, ‘Well okay, tape rolling,’ and we started — and then he **went**, ‘What was that Nathan was playing? That was much better,’ so we had to change the whole song.

Dogs, cats and birds cannot **say** anything, because they cannot speak, thus the only verb that really makes sense here is "go". I don't think this is stylistic, or a very recent innovation, as some answers seem to imply.

Answer (score 2):

Personal experience here, but I can say that growing up in the US Midwest in the 1980s, it was absolutely common for kids my age to say “goes” as a substitute for “says”.  Drove my mom nuts, but we did it.

I believe (and thought so at the time) that it has to do with the idea that you’re not simply reciting the person’s words, but imitating their mannerisms as well. *How* they said it, not just what they said.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Ylvis paid any special attention to what verb they used for their narration of animal sounds (unless they aren't good English speakers - can anyone confirm/deny?). It's simply a different way to say "says", albeit less formal. I doubt there was any special intent to create comedic effect out of "dog goes woof" beyond the rather ridiculous idea of including nursery-rhyme-esque statements in their lyrics. The verb "to go" here is nothing special. "Dog says woof" would have been just as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I’d argue **yes**, whilst it’s not a strict rule there is a specific case in play here where it’s normal.

Particularly with children, it’s a common way of expressing *characteristic* (actions/)sounds that may or may not be spoken words, including animal sounds.

So it’d be normal to say “the dog goes woof” to a child.

“Goes” obviously broader than sounds - in the song “wheels on the bus”, the “wheels go round and round”, the “baby goes wah wah wah”, and the “daddy goes shh read the paper” (at least in the version sung locally!). But it’s commonly used of characteristic actions or noises.

The lyrics of the song in question have the feel of a children’s conversation/question (part of the quirky appeal of it), so “goes” is normal to express the characteristic noises of the animals. The question is then phrased “what does the fox say?” Which - despite “say” not being entirely accurate, is the natural way to ask this of a child, as “what does the Fox go?” Or “how does the Fox go?” Are not as clear as to what is being asked.

We also see “goes” used of speech in phrases like “he was going on and on”, or “he was going on about English grammar”. However, using it of *reported* speech would be considered incorrect (in standard EN-GB at least).

Answer (score 0):

> **go** verb (NOISE)
>
> to produce a noise:
>
> *I think I heard the doorbell go (= ring) just now.*
> *I wish my computer would stop going "beep" whenever I do something wrong.*

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go)

Comment: The same definition has already been given, Jalene. The whole question is in fact a duplicate.