# Is 'broad and narrow features' metaphorical?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

When I say broad features and narrow features, are the "broad" and "narrow" here metaphors for "general" and "specific" or do they mean "big" and "small"?

Supposing broad features of the American economy and we mention one by one its employment, industries etc. Here is the word *broad* a metaphor for *general*?

Actually what I am confused about is when we say "broad" features or "narrow features" do the words "broad" and "narrow" here mean literally big and small or metaphorically general and specific? what do "broad" and "narrow" here mean?

Comment: Yes sure.What is your say on this?

Answer (score 2):

*Broad* and *narrow* are certainly [metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) in most cases. They refer to measurements of certain kinds. They're not really the same as 'general' and 'specific', though they can be used that way in some contexts.

Literally, *broad* can be used to describe a river, a path, or a road (meaning 'wide').  Note that all of them have to do with unidirectional motion along some two-dimensional path, river, road, trail of footprints, etc. It is opposed by *narrow* (meaning 'thin') in these uses.

In non-literal metaphoric use, broad and narrow usually appear as part of a [Path metaphor](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/91228/15299), like

- `Life is a Path` *He takes the straight and narrow path to salvation.*
- `Achieving a Goal is Following a Path` *He gave that problem a broad clearance.*
- `Thinking is Following a Path` *We are in broad agreement about the plans.*

In each of these the broadness or narrowness refers to the path involved, which is a further elaboration.

In the first one, *narrow* refers to the large amount of self-discipline required (or at least asserted) in order to stay within specified bounds.

In the second one, *give a wide berth* refers to avoiding a problem (itself a path metaphor) while moving to achieve some further goal -- *wide* refers specifically to the large distance between the moving agent and the problem avoided

In the third one, *broad agreement* means 'agreement in principle, without details specified' -- i.e, there is some distance between the two participants, which may get smaller as they move into closer (though not *narrower) agreement.

All of these and most metaphoric uses are idiomatic, and refer to larger metaphor schemas it's coherent with, like `Path` or `Container`.

Comment: I would take issue with "unidirectional motion along some two-dimensional path". **broad vistas**: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broad%20vistas%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en and **broad skies**  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broad%20skies%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en and **broad oceans** https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broad%20oceans%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en and **broad meadows** https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broad%20meadows%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Where **broad** means something like "expansive".

Comment: Here in the below Link. When we say Broad features of the Garo kinship. We mention one of them to be that they follow matriliny. When we say it to be a broad feature, what do we mean by broad here? If "They follow matriliny" is a broad feature how is it broad and how can some feature be more specific?

Comment: https://www.owlgen.com/question/discuss-broad-features-of-kinship-organizations-among-the-garo-in-north-east-india

Comment: Another example would be when we say broad features of the american economy, we mention one of them to be its "employment". Here too how is it broad? The feature i.e employment seems to specific to me and not broad in any sense, so we are we using the word broad here?

Comment: One more example. When we say one of the broad features of mars, we mention there their density i.e 3.9g/cc.here too how is that feature broad?

Answer (score 1):

The terms **broad** and **narrow** have a literal meaning that refers to the width of something.  A broad valley.  A narrow tunnel.

They can be used figuratively to refer to something that is abstract as if it were something physical or "concrete".

> That's a rather broad question.
>
> Can we focus on the narrow issue of whether plaintiff has standing?

There, **broad** means  encompassing many  features or elements (each of which could be dealt with on its own) and **narrow** means limited in scope.

Comment: Okay. But do they mean in the above context that I have put forward.When referring to features, obviously can't be wide so the literal meaning of broad there would be general/basic, and the meaning of narrow "specific" in a methaporical sense, right? Can General and specific be the two best synonyms?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. **general** is sometimes a decent synonym for **broad** and sometimes not.  **broad** does not mean "basic".

Comment: There is a difference between "wide" and "General". Wide has to ecompass many things but General doesn't need to. Something can be General and not have narrow elements within them.So what would be the single terms "broad" and "narrow" here?

Comment: Where is "here"? I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: Oh sorry. "Broad" articles of the consitution for suppose, here we are mentioning the Main articles and not the minor ones. So here Broad isn't ecompassing anything still it is broad, how?

Comment: But we would not say "broad articles of the constitution". We could say "That article is very broad in its scope, touching upon x, y, and z" where x, y, and z affect many aspects of society and polity.

Comment: Okay. Suppose Broad features of the American Economy, here what is broad ecompassing?

Comment: I would not say "broad features of the American economy". I have no idea what that means.

Comment: https://www.owlgen.com/question/discuss-broad-features-of-kinship-organizations-among-the-garo-in-north-east-india

Comment: Here what does broad mean then?

Comment: There it means something like "an overview which does not go into much detail".  You could say "That society is matrilineal".  That is a very broad statement, since there are differences from one matrilineal society to the next. Are all matrilineal societies alike in all respects? No.

Comment: If I simple say Broad reasons for doing this stuff, narrow reasons for doing this stiff, Broad and narrow here would mean General and Specific, right? And hence broad doesn't necessarily has to ecompass many things but has to be general, right?

Comment: The meaning of only the word "broad" here in the above contexts is General or broad in the sense Wide and big?